# Splitting strings and stacking them in one column

Tags: r

I've got a data frame with this structure:

```
> df
modifications
13-MOD:0057
13-MOD:0046
13-MOD:0051,13-MOD:0076
13-MOD:0036,13-MOD:0076,13-MOD:0016
13-MOD:0256,13-MOD:0156,13-MOD:0956,13-MOD:0125
13-MOD:0014 13-MOD:0156, 13-MOD:0956,13-MOD:0125...n
13-MOD:0012 ... n
```

To split the data I used this code:

```
df2 <- data.frame(str_split_fixed(df$modifications, ",", 20))
```

Basically, I get this data.

```
> df2
x1          | x2           | x3          | empty       |
13-MOD:0057 | empty        | empty       | empty       |
13-MOD:0046 | emply        | empty       | empty       |
13-MOD:0051 | 13-MOD:0076  | empty       | empty       |
13-MOD:0036 | 13-MOD:0076  | 13-MOD:0016 | empty       |
13-MOD:0256 | 13-MOD:0156  | 13-MOD:0956 | 13-MOD:0125
13-MOD:0014 | 13-MOD:0156  | 13-MOD:0956 | 13-MOD:0125  | ... n
13-MOD:0012 | ...          | ...n
```

What I want is remove the empty values and stack the data from columns X2,X3, X4 ... n to the first one X1.

To do that I was using this:

```
df3 <- melt(setDT(df2),                       # set df to a data.table
 measure.vars = list(c(1:20)),    # set column groupings
 value.name = 'V')[                      # set output name scheme
   , -1, with = F]
```

To remove the empty values:

```
df3[df3==""] <- NA
```

histo3 = subset(df3, V1 != 'NA')

But I don't know why I get an error about the length of the column in melt function. Do you know any way to make this easier?.

Reproducible example:

```
df <- data.frame(modifications=c("UNIMOD:108,UNIMOD:108","UNIMOD:108","UNIMOD:108","UNIMOD:108,UNIMOD:108,UNIMOD:108","UNIMOD:108,UNIMOD:108,UNIMOD:108,UNIMOD:108,UNIMOD:108,UNIMOD:108","UNIMOD:108"))
```

Comment: `read.table(text = as.character(df$modifications), fill = TRUE, sep = ',')`

Comment: @rawr ´Error in read.table(text = as.character(histo1$modifications), fill = TRUE,:duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed´

Comment: I dont get that error, try adding row.names = NULL ?

Comment: @rawr Ok, that works but I have another problem. Some data is in the second column. i66.tinypic.com/309k313.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could it be something like this?

```
library(stringr)

# input dataset
s <- c('13-MOD:0057', '13-MOD:0046', '13-MOD:0051,13-MOD:0076', '13-MOD:0036,13-MOD:0076,13-MOD:0016', '13-MOD:0256,13-MOD:0156,13-MOD:0956,13-MOD:0125')

s
[1] "13-MOD:0057"                                    
[2] "13-MOD:0046"                                    
[3] "13-MOD:0051,13-MOD:0076"                        
[4] "13-MOD:0036,13-MOD:0076,13-MOD:0016"            
[5] "13-MOD:0256,13-MOD:0156,13-MOD:0956,13-MOD:0125"

# get the individual lengths
lengths <- sapply(str_split(s,','), function(x){ length(x) })

# create the dataframe splitting in N columns
as.data.frame(str_split_fixed(s, ',', max(lengths)))

  V1          V2          V3          V4
1 13-MOD:0057                                    
2 13-MOD:0046                                    
3 13-MOD:0051 13-MOD:0076                        
4 13-MOD:0036 13-MOD:0076 13-MOD:0016            
5 13-MOD:0256 13-MOD:0156 13-MOD:0956 13-MOD:0125
```

**UPDATE 1**
To stack all the non-empty cells into a single column

```
 # create the dataframe splitting in N columns
 first.matrix <- str_split_fixed(s, ',', max(lengths))

 # select only the cells != ""  
 first.matrix[which(first.matrix!="")]

[1] "13-MOD:0057" "13-MOD:0046" "13-MOD:0051" "13-MOD:0036" "13-MOD:0256" "13-MOD:0076"
[7] "13-MOD:0076" "13-MOD:0156" "13-MOD:0016" "13-MOD:0956" "13-MOD:0125"
```

Comment: Nop. I want to stack all of then in one column.